# Array loop always returning last value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following loop:

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

var html = "";  

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var html = "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";
}
```

The output of this JS is:

```
<div class="group" data-department="Value 3">
   <div class="title">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="group" data-department="Value 3">
   <div class="title">Text 3</div>
</div>

<div class="group" data-department="Value 3">
   <div class="title">Text 3</div>
</div>
```

What I'm after is:

```
<div class="group" data-department="Value 1">
   <div class="title">Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class="group" data-department="Value 2">
   <div class="title">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="group" data-department="Value 3">
   <div class="title">Text 3</div>
</div>
```

A `console.log("Value: " + array[i]);` returns:

```
Value: Value 1
Value: Value 2
Value: Value 3
```

And a `console.log("Text: " + textArray[i]);` returns:

```
Text: Text 1
Text: Text 2
Text: Text 3
```

So unsure why my markup is being rendered based on the last item in the array?

Following the removal of var from with the loop, I'm getting the following results (container divs get nested within each other):

```js
var html = "";

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";
}
```

```html
<div class="group" data-department="Value 1">
  <div class="title">Text 1</div>
  <div class="group" data-department="Value 2">
    <div class="title">Text 2</div>
    <div class="group" data-department="Value 3">
      <div class="title">Text 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're resetting your variable every time: `var html = "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";`

Comment: just remove var from ` var html = "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>"; ` Apart from that I suggest to learn more about let, const, var. How to use it and where to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

var html = "";  

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   html += "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";


}  

console.log(html)
```

You re assigned the variable html inside your loop.This is causing the html variable to reset everytime the loop starts. At the end you'll only have the last value.

You say the values are nested but for me thats not the case:

```js
var html = "";
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];


for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";
}

console.log(html)
```

Returns :

```
<div class='group' data-department='Value 1'>
    <div class='title'>Text 1</div>
</div>

<div class='group' data-department='Value 2'>
    <div class='title'>Text 2</div>
</div>

<div class='group' data-department='Value 3'>
    <div class='title'>Text 3</div><
/div>
```

Comment: @Mridul any idea why ? this is literally the answer.

Comment: Oh i am not upset lol! Im just confused why someone would downvote for fun @gramgram

Comment: Hey @Kevin.a - Thanks for your answer, I get what I'me doing wrong. I've stopped reassigning var in the loop, but now the markup is nested. See my edit

Comment: @Freddy I just updated my question with a snippet proving to you that it doesnt nest the values.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];





var html = "";  

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";
}  

console.log(html)
```

Comment: `var` Will redeclare the variable instead of the previous one

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid using `innerHTML`, use `document.createElement` ad than set up the attributes you need. use `appendChild` to put one element into another

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const div1 = document.createElement('div')
  div1.dataset.department = array[i]
  div1.classList.add(`group`)

  const div2 = document.createElement('div')
  div2.classList.add(`title`)
  div2.innerText = textArray[i]
  
  div1.appendChild(div2)
  document.querySelector(`.parent`).appendChild(div1)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

You don't need the **var** html within the loop.

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"],
    textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"],
    html = "";  

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += "<div class='group' data-department='"+array[i]+"'>";
  html += "<div class='title'>" + textArray[i] + "</div>";
  html += "</div>";
}
console.log(html);
```